# Auto Update Swing Application - Install4J

Tags: java, swing, auto-update, install4j

I have a swing application which is deployed on Macintosh and Windows OSes. I am using Install4J for deployment. I want to use auto update feature provided by Install4J as explained in https://www.ej-technologies.com/blog/2010/12/beyond-installing/. Seems like this tutorial is very old (written in 2010) and options shown here aren't available/have changes.

Please guide me through achieving the task. I am using v7.0.6 at the moment.

Comment: The person who down voted this better provide me an example or tutorial since I am a newcomer to Java.

Comment: That person will never see your comment. However, on stackoverflow you should always have a specific problem, not ask for general guidance. Here's the link to the relevant documentation: https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/#install4j.helptopics.concepts.autoUpdate

Comment: Thanks Ingo. Cheers! I would have marked your response as an answer if you would have added it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ingo Kagel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936832/ingo-kegel) answered my question. Help for auto update functionality is provided at https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/#install4j.helptopics.concepts.autoUpdate .